# Pagination on fast changing database content

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pagination

I need to read the content of a MS SQL database table using pagination, i.e. fetching the first page of N rows, then the second page of N rows and so on.

If the content of the database is changing significantly during the pagination, a simple pagination query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT a.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rnum
    FROM articles a)
WHERE rnum <= 10
AND   rnum >= 6;
```

may not work reliably.  Inserted rows can be skipped or can cause subsequent rows to be repeated and deleted rows can cause subsequent rows to be skipped.

I could avoid such problems by doing any of the following:

1. Lock the rows against update during the entire pagination - *too
   restrictive*
2. Copy the rows to a temporary table before paging - *too slow*
3. Select by a combination of row number and the sorted value that
   was displayed at the end of the previous page, resuming at an
   appropriate place based on the changing table, but still getting
   only the next N rows

I kind of like the 3rd solution, but I find it difficult to implement when there are duplicate values in the sort column(s).

For example, let's assume I have a list of articles sorted by descending rating. If the rating is the same, they are sorted by ascending ID (the IDs are unique):

```
ID      RATING
9       34
3       32
6       32
8       32
12      32
1       25
2       23
```

Now, I want pages of 3 articles, which means the first page will have articles 9, 3 and 6. This is done by querying the top 3 articles form the sorted list.

Now, I want to take the next 3 articles resuming from article 8, using the article ID as marker for where to resume.

If I told the database to take the reputation of article 8 and than take the 3 articles which have reputation lower than that, I would skip article 12.

If I told the database to take the reputation of article 8 and than take the 3 articles which have reputation lower than or equal to that, I would repeat article 3 and 6.

What SQL query (or combination of queries) can I use to resume the pagination from article 8, using the article ID as marker for where to resume?

Comment: Unfortunately your requirements can't help but contradict themselves. Is your goal to always show the person articles they haven't seen before in this session, or is it to make sure the ranking is accurate? If I'm looking at the top 3, then someone changes ID 8 to have a ranking of 33 (pushing 6 down to the second page), you don't want to show 6 on the second page because they've already seen it? What if they go to page 1 again?

Comment: @AaronBertrand OK, good point. I want to show users articles they have not seen before. What would you do then in this case? Is caching the whole table the only solution to give a consistent results across pages?

Comment: Again, I'm not clear on your goal. Do you want the user looking at stale data even if ratings have actually changed in the meantime? If I was looking at items on eBay and the bid for one of the items went up, I'd want it to be re-sorted accurately before I bid. So what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @AaronBertrand In my case, what is really important is that one article is not repeated in the list. This is because this is often shown as a scrolling list loaded page by page, rather then separate pages like in a book. So, in a scrolling list it would be bad to see an article twice, while it would not be so bad in separate pages. Also, a static snapshot of the list would be acceptable in this case.

Comment: Then it sounds like you either need to (a) cache a copy of the list somewhere in its original sorted form or (b) stop ordering by data that can change during scrolling. What technology are you using to present this list to the end user?

Comment: @AaronBertrand The list is requested by a mobile device to a web service which retrieves the list from the database. The mobile device shows the list in a scrolling list-view which is updated page by page while scrolling. Displaying the articles ordered by descending raking is a requirement of the application.

Comment: So it seems like you should cache the result for that user (e.g. can you send *all* the IDs to the app and have it just pull 3 articles at a time on each fetch), but also add a disclaimer that if it takes them half an hour to scroll through the list, the list may no longer be accurate.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks a lot. If this had been an answer, I would have accepted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting comment to answer, since it seems to have solved the user's question.

So it seems like you should cache the result for that user (e.g. can you send all the IDs to the app and have it just pull 3 articles at a time on each fetch), but also add a disclaimer that if it takes them half an hour to scroll through the list, the list may no longer be accurate.